# JavaScript not decoding parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

So from the textarea I take the shortcode `%91samurai id="19"%93` it should be `[samurai id="19"]`:

```
var not_decoded_content = jQuery('[data-module_type="et_pb_text_forms_00132547"]')
.find('#et_pb_et_pb_text_form_content').html();
```

But when I try to decode the `%91` and `%93`

```
self.content = decodeURI(not_decoded_content);
```

I get the error:

> Uncaught URIError: URI malformed

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: The string you're trying to decode is not a URI. Try `decodeURIComponent()`

Comment: I already tried this and same error thanks for -1 `Uncaught URIError: URI malformed`

Comment: When the actual string is encoded, `[` is came as `%5B` and `]` as `%5D`, try with that.

Comment: %91 and %93 don't exist, that's why you get the error. See https://www.obkb.com/dcljr/charstxt.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encodings are **invalid**. If you can't fix the whatever-system-produces-them to **correctly** produce %5B and %5D, then your only option is to do a replacement yourself: replace all %91 with character 91 which is '[', then replace all %93 with character 93 which is ']'.

Note that javascript String Replace as-is won't do "Replace all occurrences". If you need that, then create a loop (while it contains(...) do a replace), or search the internet for `javascript replace all`, you should find plenty results.

And a final note, I am used to using `decodeURIComponent(...)`. If you can make the whatever-system-produces-them to **correctly** produce %5B and %5D, and you still get that error, then try using `decodeURIComponent(...)` instead of `decodeURI`(...).

Answer (score 0):

The string you're trying to decode is not a URI. Use `decodeURIComponent()` instead.

**UPDATE**

Hmm, that's not actually the issue, the issues are the `%91` and `%93`.

```
encodeURI('[]')
```

gives `%5b%5d`, it looks like whatever has encoded this string has used the decimal rather than hexadecimal value.

```
Decimal 91 = hex 5b
Decimal 93 = hex 5d
```

Trying again with the *hex* values

```
decodeURI('%5bsamurai id="19"%5d') == '[samurai id="19"]'
```

Comment: I already tried this and same error thanks for -1 `Uncaught URIError: URI malformed`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the solution you want to see, but can you try using "`%E2%80%98`" for `%91` and "`%E2%80%9C`" for `%93` ?

The `%91` and `%93` are part of [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters) which html does not like to decode (for reasons beyond me). Simply put, they're not your ordinary ASCII characters for HTML to play around with.